# Monitor GC Dataflow events per minute in Stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-stackdriver

I run a Google Cloud dataflow job. I know how to monitor elementCount metric coming from it. But that metric shows me the total number of events processed by the job from its start. But how to monitor the rate? Like events per timespan, per minute in Stackdriver?

Ideally, I would like to apply a simple transformation on the elementCount metric inside the Stackdriver. But I'm afraid I would need to send a separate metric computed in the Dataflow job...

Answer (score 3):

You can access all the stackdriver metrics via the API (although the elementCount is a gauge, you can fetch the time series). Here are all the dataflow metric in StackDriver:

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-dataflow

Probably you need todo some calculations on the timeseries if you want to have the correct rate per time windows.

The API timeseries documentation is here:

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rpc/google.monitoring.v3

You can even access the API's in your dataflows. Note, that I think the way the metrics is used it should have been a counter.

Comment: So there is no way to do this in Stackdriver UI? Only via API? That's a pity... That requires from me to run different monitoring UI, like Grafana. Hoping there exist such an integration, fully-featured.

Comment: Ha yes, I feel your pain. In stackdriver it produces quite useless graphs. I've filled a ticket in the public tracker, so feel free to star it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110285363

Comment: Great, Thanks Alex for this. Would you mind changing the answer to reflect that? Something like "it's impossible in UI, I requested a feature here. But here is how you can do it via API".  Then I would be glad to accept the answer. It would be useful for others searching for the solution.

Comment: Alternatively, you can fetch the time series as suggested by Alex but then push back your calculated rate into a custom metric so you can leverage it for alerting policies in Stackdriver and view the pipeline element rate graph from the Stackdriver UI.